# Is it possible to apply "Update to recommended settings" from CLI command?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

After `pod install` command Xcode suggests `Update to recommended settings`. 
I have a case when CI fails when the project doesn't update to the recommended settings. 
I'd like to know does command that could do this from the terminal exists?
Environment: 
CocoaPods : 1.10.1
Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
RubyGems : 3.0.3
Host : macOS 11.2.1 (20D74)
Xcode : 12.4 (12D4e)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is no dedicated command, but you can mute them with a script. Xcode shows these warnings if one of the `LastSwiftMigration`, `LastSwiftUpdateCheck`, `LastUpgradeCheck` or `LastTestingUpgradeCheck` is lower than the current Xcode version. Check the example we use for our projects below. `xcodeproj` uses versions in the format like "1240" for Xcode 12.4. I use "1240" in the example; change it to the value you need.

```
find . \
    -type f \
    -name "\project.pbxproj" \
    -exec sed -i.orig \
    -E "s/(LastSwiftMigration|LastSwiftUpdateCheck|LastUpgradeCheck|LastTestingUpgradeCheck){1} = (.){4}/\1 = '1240'/" {} +
```